# Method of performing Panchopachār Pūjā

Tags: puja

Panchopachār pūjā is performed by using 5 different substances. What is the Method of performing Panchopachār Pūjā?

Answer (score 4):

The Pancha Upacharas are Gandha,Dhoopa,Deepa,Pushpa & Naivedya.

**Gandham**-Sandal paste,Haridra Kumkumam,other scented objects come under this category.

**Dhoopam**-Lighted Incense Sticks.

**Deepam**-Lighted Ghee/Oil Lamps.

**Pushpam**-Flowers.

**Naivedyam**-Food offerings(like fruits,milk,sweets or cooked permissible foods).

These 5 Upacharas are offered to Gods along with chanting of few Mantras typically of the following form:

Om Bhur Bhuvah Swaha (salutations to God) Gandham dharaayami(or samarpayami),Dhoopam Aghrapayami(or samarpayami),Deepam Darsayami(or samarpayami) etc.

See the screenshot(a typical form of the Mantra used) below:

[image]

To be specific,suppose ,you are doing a Ganapaty Puja.

Then the 5 corresponding Mantras for offering the Panchopacharas will be:

> Om Bhur Bhuvah Swaha Sri Mahaganapataye Namaha Gandham Dharayami(I am
>   offering You Gandham)
>
> Om Bhur Bhuvah Swaha Sri Mahaganapataye Namaha Dhoopam Aghrapayami(I
>   am offering lighted Incense )
>
> Om Bhur Bhuvah Swaha Sri Mahaganapataye Namaha Deepam Darsayami(I am
>   waving/showing/offering lighted lamps).
>
> Om Bhur Bhuvah Swaha Sri Mahaganapataye Namaha Puspaihi Pujayami(or
>   Pushpam samarpayami)(I am worshiping with flowers or offering flowers)
>
> Om Bhur Bhuvah Swaha Sri Mahaganapataye Namaha Naivedyam Nivedayami(I
>   am offering food items)

With these 5 simple Mantras one is supposed to offer the Pancha Upacharas to Deity.

For example,chant the Mantra given above for Gandham while offering Sandal Paste and so on.

NOTE 1-If you are doing a Shiva Puja then just replace the **"Sri Mahaganapataye Namaha"** portion in above Mantras with **"Sambaparameswaraya Namaha"**.Similarly For Vishnu Puja use **"Mahavishnave Namaha"** instead.

NOTE 2-Before offering Gods these 5 Upacharas, Dhyanam (meditating upon the Deity) & Avahanam(Invoking the Divine presence) are also to be done.There are specific Mantras for that purpose.

[Source1](http://www.astrojyoti.com/ganesha.htm).[Source2](http://www.hindunet.org/day_as_hindu/puja/shortpuja.htm)

Answer (score 2):

**Applying gandha (Sandalwood paste) & haldī (Turmeric) – kumkum (Vermillion) to the Deity**

> Apply gandha to the Deity with the ring finger of the right hand.
>   Then, offer haldī-kumkum at the Deity’s feet by taking a pinch of each
>   between the thumb and ring finger of the right hand. First offer haldī
>   and then offer kumkum.

**Offering patrī and flowers to the Deity**

> - Do not offer artificial flowers (made out of paper or plastic or    decorative flowers) to a Deity. Fresh and sāttvik flowers should be
>     offered to Deities.
> - Do not smell the flowers and patrī that are to be offered to the    Deity.
> - Patrī should be offered before offering the flowers.
> - Offer leaves and flowers to a Deity that attracts the Principle of    the Deity to the maximum extent. For example, bēl (Leaves of Aegle
>     marmelos tree) to Deity Shiva and durvā and a red flower to Shrī
>     Ganapati. While offering durvā to the Idol of Shrī Ganapati, cover
>     the entire body with durvā except the face. Durvā offered to Shrī
>     Ganapati are changed thrice a day. For this reason, pūjā of Shrī
>     Ganapati is performed thrice a day.
> - Specific Deities must be offered a specific number of flowers and    that too arranged in a specific pattern. For example, Shrī Ganapati
>     should be offered 8 flowers in rhomboid shape, and Deity Hanumān
>     should be offered five flowers in elliptical shape. Ensure that these 
>     flowers are not placed in an uneven manner.
> - When offering flowers to the Deities placed in the temple at home,    recite the Name of the Upāsyadēvatā (Deity of worship) and then begin 
>     by offering small flowers of dark colour first, followed by
>     medium-size lighter colour flowers and last, offer big white flowers. 
>     In a conical arrangement of Deities, only upon offering flowers to
>     Shrī Ganapati placed at the apex of the cone, proceed to the next
>     stage; in the second stage, offer flowers to other superior Male
>     Deities. Thereafter, offer flowers to the Female counterpart of the
>     Male Deity followed by the Deity’s sub-forms.
> - Flowers should be offered at the Deity’s feet instead of on the head.
> - While offering a flower, the stalk should be towards the Deity.

**Waving lit dhoop or lit incense-stick in front of the Deity**

> - Do not disperse smoke emitting from dhoop with the hands.
> - After waving the dhoop, wave incense-sticks of a specific fragrance    in front of the Deity, which attracts the respective Deity’s
>     Principle to a greater extent. For example, wave heena (A kind of
>     herb) incense-sticks to Deity Shiva and rose incense-sticks to Shrī
>     Lakshmī.
> - The number of incense-sticks required for waving in front of the    Deity: In general, a seeker in the initial stage of Shakti worship
>     should wave five incense-sticks, those who perform pūjā as part of
>     their duty should wave two incense-sticks and a seeker who performs
>     upāsanā with bhāv (Spiritual emotion) and devotion should wave one
>     incense-stick. The incense-sticks should be waved thrice in front of
>     the Deity.
> - While waving dhoop or incense-sticks in front of the Deity, sound the    bell with the left hand.
>
> **Waving a lit lamp in front of the Deity**
>
> - A lit lamp should be waved clockwise in front of the Deity thrice,    while simultaneously ringing the bell with the left hand.
> - Points to be remembered when lighting a lamp
> - Do not use a lit lamp to light another lamp.
> - An oil lamp should not be used to light a ghee
> - Change the wick of the lamp placed in the temple at home daily.

**Offering Naivēdya to a Deity**

> - While preparing Naivēdya, less amount of red chilli powder, salt and oil should be used; sāttvik substances such as ghee (Clarified
>     butter) should be used in ample quantity.
> - Banana leaf should be used for offering Naivēdya.
> - Salt should not be served on the leaf prepared for Naivēdya to a Deity.
> - Keep the leaf (on which the Naivēdya has been served) covered.
> - When offering Naivēdya, first pray to the Ishtadēvatā and draw a mandal (Circle or protective sheath) on the floor in front of the
>     Deity. Then place the banana leaf (or plate) containing Naivēdya on
>     this mandal with the stalk of the leaf towards the Deity and the tip
>     of the leaf towards yourself.
> - While offering Naivēdya, water should be sprinkled clockwise around the banana leaf or the plate only once (this act is known as drawing a
>     mandal). Water should not be sprinkled anticlockwise again.
> - The act of offering Naivēdya to a Deity

**Different acts to be performed after completion of the Pūjā**

> - Lighting a karpūr-deep (Camphor lamp): Although the upachār of lighting a karpūr-deep is not included in Panchopachār pūjā, yet due
>     to the sāttviktā of camphor, this act imparts greater sāttviktā.
>     Hence, after offering Naivēdya, karpūr-deep can be lit.
> - Sound the conch and perform Āratī of the Deity with bhāv.
> - After imbibing the Āratī, apply Vibhūti (Holy ash) from the origin of the nose to the mid-brow region.
> - Drink Tīrtha (Sacred liquid) thrice. Take Tīrtha in the middle of the right palm and drink it. Then, after touching the middle of the
>     palm with the tip of the middle finger and ring finger, touch the eyes
>     with these fingers. Rub these fingers lightly from the forehead to the
>     head in the upward direction.
> - In the end, partake Prasād (Holy sacrament) and wash your hands.

[Source](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/method-of-performing-panchopachar-puja)